# keep dataframe portions based on values for a given column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I used the following line of code to remove the data where the “dataset_id” equals to 0. Here `data_full` is a dataframe and `dataset_id` is a column

```
data = data_full[data_full.dataset_id != 0 ]
```

If I want to remove the data where the dataset_id equals to more than just 0, how should I rewrite the above code?

I tried `data = data_full[(data_full.dataset_id != 0) &  (data_full.dataset_id != 1)]`
It gave me error such as

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I

Comment: Your code should work. But better use `df[~df['dataset_id'].isin([1,3])]`